# Multiple Azure SQL Firewall Rules in One Expression

Tags: azure-sql-database, firewall, rules

How do I set MULTIPLE [database-level firewall rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#manage-firewall-rules-using-transact-sql) in one SQL expression? I have many IP addresses to whitelist over multiple DB's. I'm looking to do something like the following:

```
EXECUTE sp_set_database_firewall_rule
@name = N'Test1',
@start_ip_address = 'x.x.x.x', @end_ip_address = 'x.x.x.x',
@name = N'Test2',
@start_ip_address = 'x.x.x.x', @end_ip_address = 'x.x.x.x',
@name = N'Test3',
@start_ip_address = 'x.x.x.x', @end_ip_address = 'x.x.x.x',
@name = N'Test4',
@start_ip_address = 'x.x.x.x', @end_ip_address = 'x.x.x.x',
@name = N'Test5',
@start_ip_address = 'x.x.x.x', @end_ip_address = 'x.x.x.x',,
@name = N'Test6',
@start_ip_address = 'x.x.x.x', @end_ip_address = 'x.x.x.x',
@name = N'Test7',
@start_ip_address = 'x.x.x.x', @end_ip_address = 'x.x.x.x'
```

Running the query above did NOT work. I had to input 1 at a time. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Before I answer the question, I have to ask the method you are using to deploy infrastructure to Azure. Are you using ARM templates or Powershell cmdlets? 

If so, it would be worth considering having the rules handled by your provisioning pipeline by adding the list of ips as parameters to your ARM template/powershell script.

Comment: Not using ARM templates, nor Powershell cmdlets. Using Azure Portal or Azure CLI to create Resource Groups, SQL Servers, and Databases. Using Azure Portal to create Firewall Rules. Using SQL Server Mgmt. Studio to create SQL tables.

Comment: My understanding is that database-level firewall rules can only be created with T-SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just making sure we are talking about the same thing. Hopefully my answer below will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated in your question the syntax your are trying to execute is not supported by T-SQL. What you could do is use dynamic SQL to make it easier-use only one statement:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

;WITH iplists (IPAddrStart, IPAddrEnd, RuleName) AS 
(
    SELECT '100.0.0.0', '100.0.0.1', 'name0'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '100.0.0.2', '100.0.0.3', 'name1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '100.0.0.4', '100.0.0.5', 'name2'
)
SELECT @SQL+= 'EXECUTE sp_set_database_firewall_rule @name = N''' + iplists.RuleName 
+ ''', @start_ip_address = ''' + iplists.IPAddrStart + ''', @end_ip_address = ''' + 
iplists.IPAddrEnd + '''; ' + CHAR(13)
FROM iplists;

--PRINT @SQL;
EXEC (@SQL);
```

Comment: Thank you for your expertise. Question: In your example shown, are IP ranges possible? Example: 1.1.1.1 - 1.1.1.10 or does each IP address need to be listed individually?

Comment: Yes the range is possible. You have to remember that SQL Azure defines ip range as inclusive on both ends so in the above example the first rule will allow both 100.0.0.0 and 100.0.0.1. Change the IPAddrEnd field of the CTE to your required value (e.g. 100.0.0.10) and you will have a range rule.

Comment: ! Excellent answer and many thanks. You just made my life a lot easier. Your solution worked flawlessly. I just ran a script (based on yours) for 22 database-level firewall rules. Then ran `SELECT * FROM sys.database_firewall_rules ORDER BY name;` and all show up. Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know the above works for most if you want an address range per line. I wanted something a little easier in copying and pasting.

This worked for me because I just wanted the same IP start and end - so something like this worked well:

```
DECLARE @tempThings TABLE
      (
          ipaddr NVARCHAR(30)
      );
INSERT  @tempThings
VALUES
    ( '100.0.0.0' )
   ,( '100.0.0.65' )
   ,( '100.0.0.76' );
  

SELECT
    *
   ,'EXECUTE sp_set_firewall_rule ' + 'N''Name '
    + CONVERT (NVARCHAR(5), CAST(RAND (CHECKSUM (NEWID ())) * 1000 AS INT)) + ''',' + '''' + [ipaddr] + ''',' + ''''
    + [ipaddr] + '''' + ';' [CommandList]
    FROM    @tempThings;
```

Produces:

[image]